# Key Bind Reader Script

Tags: lua, roblox

I FIXED IT! Yeeeeeeees.

Ok, so I made a Key Bind script, that sets a IntValue to the byte code of a Key you press. That works all fine.
The problem is that the script that reads the Key Bind part doesn't work.
Here is the script:

```
print("Running KeyCheck script")
KeyValue = script.Parent.KeyValue

function onChanged(Value)
    print("Changed: " .. Value)
end

KeyValue.Changed:connect(onChanged)
```

It's in a Local Script, in the player. KeyValue is the IntValue I mentioned earlier.
I don't get any errors, but none of the prints well, print anything.

Thanks in advance,
Sil3nt

Comment: You should tell us how you did it, and accept a answer, even if it is your own.

Comment: I just need the KeyBind script to not be Local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. Just had to set the KeyBind script to not local. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
As long as `script.Parent.KeyValue` exists, it should work.

One thing you might wanna know is when any type of "Value" object is changed, it returns the value, not which property was changed.

I think you might already know that.

You might try it in a regular script.

Comment: Well, it doesn't even run for some reason.
And yes I know the value thing.

Comment: The player, an onEntered script puts it there.